# Calculate minutes between two times without date

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have two times that I would like to calculate the difference in minutes between them. They are as follows:

```
startDate = "23:51"
endDate = "00:01"
```

They are both of type `String` as subsequently do not have a date attached with them. I know the common practice would be to convert both to `Date` and then calculate the difference in time using `NSCalendar`:

```
extension Date {
    func minutes(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.components(.minute, from: date, to: self, options: []).minute ?? 0
    }
}
```

However this produces the incorrect result as the days, months, etc. are unknown. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Note that the answer depends on the timezone and the day: There could be a daylight saving time transition at midnight.

Comment: The solution is ambiguous as written unless you make some assumptions. Do you want to assume that the times always occur on the same date? If so the problem is pretty simple. If not, what rules do you want to use to decide when the times fall on different dates?

Comment: If day and mont are unknown they shouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: I think my answer is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic way to find the difference without using `NSDate`:

```
let startDate = "23:51"
let endDate = "00:01"

let startArray = startDate.componentsSeparatedByString(":") // ["23", "51"]
let endArray = endDate.componentsSeparatedByString(":") // ["00", "01"]

let startHours = Int(startArray[0])! * 60 // 1380
let startMinutes = Int(startArray[1])! + startHours // 1431

let endHours = Int(endArray[0])! * 60 // 0
let endMinutes = Int(endArray[1])! + endHours // 1

var timeDifference = endMinutes - startMinutes // -1430

let day = 24 * 60 // 1440

if timeDifference < 0 {
    timeDifference += day // 10
}
```

And at the end `timeDifference` equals `10`.

This function is assuming that the end date will take place after the start date no matter what. So if the end date is a time that is before the start date it will add 1440 minutes (1 day). It also assumes that the dates are in the format "hh:mm" where the hours range from 0 to 24 and minutes range from 0 to 60.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for, thank you.